# How can I tell autoinst to use tabular lining figures the package default?

Tags: fonts, autoinst

I am using autoinst to convert a set of fonts. Autoinst also creates sty-files for each font and according to the documentation (https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/texlive-core/autoinst.1.en) the resulting sty-files behaves like:

> "lining", "oldstyle", "tabular", "proportional"
> Choose which figure style to use. The defaults are "oldstyle" and "proportional" (if available).

In the past however I remember that autoinst was able to also select different default styles, as https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/branch2022/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/fontools/autoinst#L1124 and https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/branch2022/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/fontools/autoinst#L1192 indicate.

But as far as I see in the latest version (https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/trunk/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/fontools/autoinst), there is no trace of `\ExecuteOptionsX` whatsoever. So is there a way to tell autoinst to make lining, tabular the default figure style without manual intervention of the .sty file after creation?

Technically what I need is the line `\ExecuteOptionsX{lining,tabular}` in the style file.

Comment: skimming the documentation I would say  try `--defaultlining --defaulttabular`.

Comment: As far as I understand the documentation, these options are meant to be used only with fonts that only have one type of figures and no proper attribution. I fear that because the current version has no ExecuteOptionsX in the Perl-Code, currently there is no mechanism to define another default.